# making a page accessible only after login

Tags: php, html, sql

here is the login for login.php:

```
<?php
     session_start();
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];  
     include 'includes/connect.php';

     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $username );
     $query = "SELECT password, salt FROM member WHERE username = '$username';";

     $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query );

    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) == 0 ) { // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
       header('Location: login.html');
    }

    $userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );

    if ( $hash != $userData['password'] ) {
       header('Location: login.html');
    } else { // Redirect to home page after successful login.
       $_SESSION['username'] = $userData['username'];
       header('Location: stats.php');
    }
?>
```

and here is the  script for stats.php

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   if ( !isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) {
       header("Location:register.html");
   }
?>
```

I'm trying to make this page only accessible if your logged in however anyone can access stats.php.

Comment: try dumping $_SESSION with `print_r($_SESSION);` and see if the session is actually set

Comment: possible duplicate of [php session login issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757248/php-session-login-issue)

Comment: If you clear cookies for the site and try again does it let you in?

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: If I enter a username of `' OR 1=1 OR username='`, then I will always get logged in.

Answer (score 0):

In your register page, add:

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   if ( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) {
       header("Location:stats.php");
   }
?>
```